In a React Native project after adding npm package do i have to do anything else?
I am a ReactNative noob.
I have a new 17.1 project. I have added a new SDK by executing at the root of the project
npm install --save react-native-onesignal

It appears to install and i see the dependency in the package.json.
I then run
npx react-native run-ios

But when the app runs it seems like the ios does not see the onesignal SDK.
Am I missing a step for IOS after running npm install?
The reason i do not think the IOS sees the onesignal SDK is onesignal support had me put in verbose debugging command and we are not seeing any debug output.
Thanks for any help

If you your iOS couldn't see the dependency, you can go to the iOS directory and run pod install:
cd ios
pod install

